# How to filter one to many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, filter, realm

I have two models

```
class Survey: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var campaign: Campaign?
    dynamic var lat = 0.0
    dynamic var lng = 0.0
    dynamic var duration = ""
    dynamic var week = ""
    dynamic var desc = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Campaign: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var date_start = ""
    dynamic var date_end = ""
    dynamic var desc = ""
    let surveys = List<Survey>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

They are populated in a table view controller, with a `UISearchBar` on top.
Section header = campaign name, row cell are the info of the survey.

How can I filter/query from my Realm so that Campaigns that have 0 survey won't be shown(including quick search query).

At the moment my app still shows the section with 0 row.

I did

```
self.campaigns = self.realm.objects(Campaign).filter("surveys.@count > 0")
```

But however, this will not work for filtering :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the version of Realm earlier than v0.96, you should use v0.96 or later. Since Collection Keypath Queries (`@count, @sum, etc.`) has been supported from v0.96.

> Keypath collection queries using @count, @min, @max, @sum and @avg are now supported on RLMArray/List properties. See our handy NSPredicate Cheatsheet for more details on how to use these.

https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.96.0/

Comment: I'm using 0.96, hence I can "self.campaigns = self.realm.objects(Campaign).filter("surveys.@count > 0")"
But what how do I filter again with uisearchbar, cause those campaigns are now count 0 still persist with 0 row, I want to totally remove the campaign(section count)

Comment: How about results of `print(self.realm.objects(Campaign))`? Campaign and Survey objects stored in Realm correctly?

Comment: Yes, they are. Basically my question is, is there a way to search all my surveys, and only add once to a new campaign result for my sections